# chrome fails to scroll select option with mouse?

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, version

i am using chrome latest `Version 32.0.1700.76 m` this version doesn't scroll select options with mouse is this a problem just with my machine or is it a bug?

here is the fiddle for http://jsfiddle.net/4mh6b/

you can try with the select options present on the left side(Frameworks & Extensions) of the jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug which you can see from this thread of chromium bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334227

You can follow these steps:

1. Right click the Chrome icon on your Windows Desktop
2. Click Properties
3. Select the Compatibility Tab
4. Check "Disable Visual Themes" (Click OK to acknowledge)

Remember to restart your chrome browser to make it works :)

Comment: what can i do to over come this problem?

Comment: Looks like Google has fixed this in today's update. http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.co.uk/2014/01/stable-channel-update_27.html. [Bug 334454](http://crbug.com/334454) is a duplicate of the bug @Felix linked to.